# Excel 2013 code to generate an image produces a blank image in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, vba

I used a macro to generate an image of an invoice using Excel 2013.

In Excel 2016 the macro creates a blank image. It does not throw an error.

```
Sub saveimage()
Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
output = "F:\Invoices\" & Range("e8") & ".png"
zoom_coef = 100 / Sheet.Parent.Windows(1).Zoom
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Invoice")
Set StartCell = Range("A1")

'Refresh UsedRange
  Worksheets("Invoice").UsedRange

'Find Last Row
  LastRow = sht.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

'Select Range
  sht.Range("A1:N" & LastRow).Select
Set area = Selection
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
Set chartobj = Sheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
chartobj.Chart.Paste
chartobj.Chart.Export output, "png"
chartobj.Delete
End Sub
```

What could be the cause of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is some kind of bug which can be fixed by selecting the past area before pasting to it. So, you should add the following line

```
chartobj.Chart.Parent.Select
```

just before

```
chartobj.Chart.Paste
```

then you will get the requested output file. Just to be sure I'll post here the **last few lines only** of your `Sub` to illustrate where the line has to be inserted:

```
Set area = Selection
area.CopyPicture xlPrinter
Set chartobj = Sheet.ChartObjects.Add(0, 0, area.Width * zoom_coef, area.Height * zoom_coef)
chartobj.Chart.Paste
chartobj.Chart.Export output, "png"
chartobj.Delete
End Sub
```

Comment: edited png to jpg in 2 places, but still getting a blank white image.

Comment: removing `chartobj.Delete` does give a blank chart. getting a runtime error "CopyPicture method of Range class failed" when i replaced `area.CopyPicture xlPrinter` with `area.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlBitmap` and `area.CopyPicture xlScreen, xlBitmap` is also giving a blank image and replacing with gif also gives a blank image

Comment: @Ahmed: I think I have finally figured it out. Sorry for the long delay. Let me know if it works now. BTW, now you can also keep the `PNG` format which is superior to the `GIF` format. If it works out as expected then I propose that we remove all comments and clean up this post for others to find and share. But you have certainly found a "glitch" within Excel 2016 with this one.

Comment: That did it. Thanks a ton. I have been trying to figure out this since a long time, and cant thank you enough for getting me through this mess

Answer (score 0):

Change .png to .jpg in below lines

```
output = "F:\Invoices\" & Range("e8") & ".png"
```

and

```
chartobj.Chart.Export output, "png"
```

Keashan